# ANTRL4: Extracting expressions from languages

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a programming language that has many constructs in it however I am only interested in extracting expressions from the language.

Is that possible to do without having to write the entire grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, its possible.  You want what is called an "island parser".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_grammar.    You might not actually
decide to do this, more below.

The essential idea is to provide detailed grammar rules for the part of the language ("islands") you care about, and sloppy rules for the rest ("water").

The detailed grammar rules... you write as would normally write them.  This includes building a lexer and parser to parse the part  you want.

The "water" part is implemented as much as  you can by defining sloppy lexemes.  You may need more than one, and you will likely have to handle nested structures e.g.,  things involving  "("...")"   "["..."] and "{" ... "}" and you will end up doing with explicit tokens for the boundaries of these structures, and recursive grammar rules that keep track of the nesting (because lexers being FSAs typically can't track this).

Not obvious when you start, but painfully obvious after you are deep into this mess is skipping over long comment bodies, and especially string literals with the various quotes allowed by the language (consider Python for an over the top set) and the escaped sequences inside.  You'll get burned by languages that allow interpolated strings when you figure out that you have the lex the raw string content separately from the interpolated expressions, because these are also typically nested structures.  PHP and C# allow arbitrary expressions in their interpolated strings.... including expressions which themselves can contain... more interpolated strings!

The upside is all of this isn't really hard technically, if you ignore the sweat labor to dream up and handle all the funny cases.

... but ...  considering typical parsing goals, island grammars tend to fall apart when used for this purpose.

To process expressions, you usually need the language declarations that provide types for the identifiers.    If you leave them in the "ocean" part... you don't get type declarations and now it is hard to reason about your expressions.  If you are processing java, and you encounter (a+b), is that addition or string concatenation?  Without type information you just don't know.

If you decide you need the type information, now you need the detailed grammar for the variable and type declarations.   And suddenly you're a lot closer to a full parser.   At some point, you bail and just build a full parser; then you don't have think about whether you've cheated properly.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t mention your language, but there’s a good chance that there’s an ANTLR grammar for it here [ANTLR Grammars](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4)

These grammars will parse the entire contents of the source (by doing this, you can avoid some “messiness” that can come with trying decide when to pop into, and out of, island grammars, which could be particularly messy for expressions since they can occur in so many places within a typical source file.)

Once you have the resulting ParseTree, ANTLR provides a Listener capability that allows you to call a method to walk the tree and call you back for only those parts you are interested in.  In your case that would be expressions.

A quick search on ANTLR Listeners should turn up several resources on how to write a Listener for your needs.  ([This](https://www.baeldung.com/java-antlr) is a pretty short article that covers the basics (in this case, for when you’re only interested in methods, but expressions would be similar.  There are certainly others).

Comment: My experience is that having a grammar that worked for somebody else, means you don't have a grammar that works for you.  The problem is that every language comes in a variety of dialects, most of which don't match what you have to actually parse.   Granted, there's some hope that even the wrong dialect grammar can be bent to what you with modest effort.   Just don't believe it is likely to be zero effort.

Comment: This can certainly happen.  It's more likely with things like SQL where different vendors have different dialects of SQL.  More general purpose languages (Java, for example) are probably kept more up to date, and more likely to parse your input.  With expressions, particularly, you're going to have a LOT of difficulty finding them in your input without parsing the whole input. Island grammars generally have markers for shifting in and out, and you won't have that for expressions.  I didn't mean to imply that you could just grab a grammar and not look back, but it's quicker than "from scratch"

Comment: Yes, the Java grammar is probably pretty good because the Java team has worked hard to define it carefully and generally in backwards compatible ways.    I've done parsers for some 40 languages, and I practically never find a suitable grammar (ANTLR, Bison, ... whatever parser generator  you want to suggest)  for what I actually have.  Yes, they can be head starts.